# Trouble accessing settings API to check enabled/disabled in Salesforce

Tags: python-3.x, rest, soap, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I'm trying to write test cases in Python which basically check whether a particular setting in salesforce is enabled or not.
I'm currently trying to check whether Multi-Factor authentication for my Org is enabled/disabled through API calls. I have a dev account with Salesforce and when I went through the documentation in salesforce ,i came to know that these settings are present under `metadata types > settings > SecuritySettings > SessionSettings > 'enableU2F'`

found in this URL : `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm`

But i'm not able to find/access it through API to check it's status.
So far i've been able to do -

```
from salesforce_api import Salesforce
import requests
client = Salesforce(username='myname@mycompanyname.salesforce',
                     password='xxx-xxx-xxx',
                     security_token='securitytokensecuritytoken')

response = requests.get('https://mycompanyname-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/metadata/deployRequest',
                         headers=client.connection.session.headers,
```

Is this the right approach ?
Is what i'm trying to access even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm) to pull metadata.

Check what fields you get back when calling `/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/SessionSettings/describe`

And experiment with query `/services/data/v54.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+IsU2Fenabled+FROM+SessionSettings`

Comment: Thank you very much @eyescream
The ```/services/data/v54.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+IsU2Fenabled+FROM+SessionSettings``` does the trick!
I'll explore more API endpoints as well for checking other settings from your method.

Comment: glad I could help! It's bit evil, settings objects aren't mentioned in the Tooling APIs reference, you really need these `/tooling/sobjects` calls to see full list specific to your org and work from there

Comment: Also , able to access the `Require security tokens for API logins from callouts (API version 31.0 and earlier)` from the Security Settings > Session Settings in Salesforce Dashboard , but see no API for this under sobjects/
Please help

Comment: How badly you need it? Salesforce is killing api versions < 30 in May 2023 anyway. Any API over that version demands security token (or logging in from trusted IP) anyway. Try flipping it on and off and check setup audit trail, there might be a hint where it's stored?